# R reading an adjacency list from file

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-list

I have an output.csv file with adjacency list of a graph. It is in the following format..

Every line starts with the source node (which is an integer) followed by the nodes it is connected to. The nodes are separated from each other and from the source node by a space (' ') separator..

A snapshot looks as follows:

```
0 2 5 8
1 2 7 4 6
2 0 1
3 4 7 8
4 1 3
```

I want to read this into an adjacency list format and use it to plot in igraph. What is the simplest way to do this ? Thanks..

Comment: Without more details, you should probably try `dat <- read.csv("yourfile.csv")` which will give a data frame. Try `str(dat)` to take a look.  Then possibly `M <- as.matrix(dat)`.  This will be suitable for `igraph`. If the row and column names are important to you (they probably will be), edit your question and paste in the result of `dput(head(dat))`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick answer!

I tried exactly as you said, It did read into the matrix M but I get the following error

Error in .Call("R_igraph_adjlist", adjlist, mode, duplicate, PACKAGE = "igraph") : 
  At structure_generators.c:84 : Invalid (negative) vertex id, Invalid vertex id
In addition: Warning messages:

I used my file test.csv looking exactly as the following

0 2 5;

1 2 4;

2 0 1;

3 4;

4 1 3;

5 0;

Thanks!

Comment: OK, post `dput(dat)` or `dput(head(dat))` if the file is quite large, and we'll troubleshoot from there.

Comment: No the file is not large as I am using only the small snapshot I mentioned.. the output is as follows

`structure(list(V1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("0 2 5 ", "1 2 4", 
"2 0 1", "3 4", "4 1 3", "5 0"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))`

Comment: Hmm... This is a very strange structure.  Go back to the csv, and make sure that it really is a csv and not say some Excel native format.  Check the details of `?read.csv` for options during the read-in.  Looks like it read in three columns as one strange entry and put it into one column.  Also inspect the csv for hidden spaces by the numbers.  Also, if there are missing values, which there seem to be, maybe code them in the csv as `NA`.  Then try to read it in again.  Check what the separator is - default is comma, maybe you have spaces instead.

Comment: Ok thanks! I called the file test.csv but it had separator as space as I mentioned in the question..

Based on your comment I changed the test.csv to have separator as comma and then `dput(dat)` gives the following structure: `structure(list(V1 = 0:5, V2 = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L), V3 = c(5, 
4, 1, NA, 3, NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))` Does this look better ?

Comment: In which case I get the same error on doing `graph.adjlist(M)`

`Error in .Call("R_igraph_adjlist", adjlist, mode, duplicate, PACKAGE = "igraph") : 
  At structure_generators.c:84 : Invalid (negative) vertex id, Invalid vertex id`

Comment: Don't try to plot it until the data is read in correctly. So right now you are using `dat <- read.csv("test.csv", sep = " ")`?  Something is still not right, as your data is being treated as factors.  You could add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to `read.csv`  Also, you can't have missing values so in the csv put `NA` where a value is missing (your original sample data has 3, 4 or 5 columns, all rows should have 5 columns I guess).  If space is your separator make sure it is exactly one space between each entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is not a proper adjacency list, because it is missing the lists for 5-8. So I just removed these vertices from your list.

Igraph has a function to create a graph from an adjacency list, so you just need to read in the data, and create the graph from the adjacency list with `graph.adjlist`. Here is one way to do it, not necessarily the simplest:

```
## magrittr for the %>% pipes
library(magrittr)
library(igraph)

## sample data
text <- "0 2\n1 2 4\n2 0 1\n3 4\n4 1 3"

## read in as lines, replace textConnection(text) with your file name
lines <- readLines(textConnection(text))

g <- lines %>% 
  strsplit(split = " ") %>%     # 1
  lapply(as.numeric) %>%        # 2
  lapply(extract, -1) %>%       # 3
  lapply(add, 1) %>%            # 4
  graph.adjlist(mode = "all")   # 5

g
#> IGRAPH U--- 5 4 -- 
#> + edges:
#> [1] 1--3 2--3 2--5 4--5
```

Some explanation for the long pipe steps:

1. We split the lines at single spaces.
2. Convert them to numeric.
3. Drop the first number from each line, this is not needed for `graph.adjlist`.
4. Add one to all numbers, since igraph vertex ids start with one, yours seem to start with zero.
5. Call `graph.adjlist` to create an undirected graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The explanation is really helpful. The only thing I didn't understand in your code is %>% and I also get the following error `Error: could not find function "%>%"` Is this some package I need to install ? Or you mean I should write the code as `strsplit(split = " ", lines)` and so on ?

Comment: @user3580099 - Gabor mentioned the `library` calls at the top of the code :) It's in `magrittr`